# How to get the same firebug "network" part information?

Tags: php, dom, networking, symfony, curl

Is there any API that can offer access to information of a web page downloading (download CSS/images, time of download, etc ...) ?

Maybe even the interface ?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something only for Symfony 2 or in general?

Comment: Consider [google pagespeed insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v1/getting_started)

Comment: Actually am building an app with SF2 that can do somthing like this, So , yes it might be perfect if it exists in symfony, ifnot => PHP or Curl api :)

Comment: @moonwave99 : I 've checked the Pagespeed API, and I noticed that i must have an API KEY for each projet (web site) I monitor !

Comment: That would be akward if i tell the user to enter his own API Key (He would simply switch to google's instead :) )

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony 2.2.0 there is a new feature called stopwatch, it might be useful.

> As you might have guessed now, the Stopwatch component provides a way to measure the execution time of specific parts of your code. In Symfony, it is heavily used by the profiler to gather information about what happens during the handling of request and how much time is spent in each layer.

You can read about it [here](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-new-stopwatch-component).

Comment: Thanks @Andrew but as i noticed, this cencerns only Symfony projects.

Comment: Am willing to use it in a symfony 2 projet but to measure on all other projects